# JQuery loading issue on submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

On my website. Im having trouble with JQuery. Im not an expert here so please understand.

Here it is the script that I'm using its working actually but, once you click the submit btn..even you have an incomplete info in the  form the loader still show processing. Even the my board says: please complete your..., still the loading gif is running.

The Script:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on( "click", ".show-page-loading-msg", function() {
  var $this = $( this ),
  theme = $this.jqmData( "theme" ) || $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme,
  msgText = $this.jqmData( "msgtext" ) || $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text,
  textVisible = $this.jqmData( "textvisible" ) || $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible,
  textonly = !!$this.jqmData( "textonly" );
  html = $this.jqmData( "html" ) || "";
$.mobile.loading( 'show', {
  text: msgText,
  textVisible: textVisible,
  theme: theme,
  textonly: textonly,
  html: html
  });
})
.on( "click", ".hide-page-loading-msg", function() {
  $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
});
</script>
```

My php code: (This is not complete i just want to share the end part)

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                        <?if (Core::config('general.recaptcha_active')):?>
                            <?=Captcha::recaptcha_display()?>
                            <div id="recaptcha3"></div>
                        <?else:?>
                            <?= FORM::label('captcha', _e('Captcha'), array('for'=>'captcha'))?>
                            <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block"><?=captcha::image_tag('publish_new')?></span>
                            <?= FORM::input('captcha', "", array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'captcha', 'required', 'data-error' => __('Captcha is not correct')))?>
                        <?endif?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?endif?>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                      <?= FORM::button('submit', __('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i>&nbsp; Publish New Ad'), array('type'=>'submit', 'data-corners'=>'false', 'class'=>'pub-new show-page-loading-msg', 'data-theme'=>'b', 'data-textonly'=>'false', 'data-msgtext'=>'Processing....', 'data-textvisible'=>'true', 'action'=>Route::url('post_new',array('controller'=>'new','action'=>'index'))))>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    <?= FORM::close()?>
```

To know more Please you can go here, but you need to use mobile to see : https://linkinads.com/publish-new.html or here in youtube for video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKzabE2eJN0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is a submit button. These button fire an event to process the form natively in HTML.

In your Javascript, instead of binding your code to the click event for the class of the button, you should instead bind it to the submit event of the form (which is tied to the button and the form as a whole) and then block the default submit action. Something like the below.

```
$('#publish-new').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //Prevents the default form event from firing
  //Rest of your code can go here
});
```

Comment: or I need to edit the beginning of form here                                           `<=FORM::open(Route::url('post_new',array('controller'=>'new','action'=>'index')), array('class'=>'form-horizontal', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', 'data-ajax'=>'false'))?>`

Comment: Please show im not an expert here please. Thank  you

Answer (score 1):

though I dont know the real issued here but after i move this, things are fixed

`'data-ajax'=>'false'`

solve my issue.